# How do I print out factors of an input using loops?

Tags: java, loops, factors

Here is my mess of a code. I have to write a program that inputs a positive integer greater than 3. Validate that the integer is in fact greater than 3. Then print all possible pairs of positive integers great than whose product is less than or equal to the number entered.

```
ex. If 24 is the input.
It would print:
4 = 2 x 2 
6 = 2 x 3
8 = 2 x 4
10 = 2 x 5
12 = 2 x 6
14 = 2 x 7
16 = 2 x 8....
9 = 3 x 3
12 = 3 x 4..
24 = 3 x 8...
all the way to 
24 = 4 x 6

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Factors {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Define Variables
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        int k = 2;
        int product = 0;
        // Ask for input/loop
        while (i < 3) {
            System.out.println("Please enter an integer greater than 3");
            i = input.nextInt();
        }
        while (product < i) {
            if (product == i) { j++; k = 2; 
        for (j = 2; product < i; k++) {
                product = j * k;
                System.out.println(product + " = " + j + " x " + k);
                if (product == i) { j++; k = 2; 
                }   
            }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. And your problem exactly is...?

Comment: It looks like you want an inputValue, and list all products of integer that are < to this inputValue.

Am i right ? if yes, i do have a piece of code that does the trick.

But first, you should ask yourself : what do I want to do ? what does my current code do ?

Comment: Sorry, I guess I could have been more clear. With the above code, I can get  output of all the factors with 2 so 2 x = 4... the whole way up to whatever my input value is. However, I have no idea how to do the rest so i can do 3, 4, etc. I'm rather lost with where to go next or what to even do. I need it to print out all possible factors without repeating any such as 2 x 3 = 6 and 3 x 2 = 6.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Factors {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Define Variables
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i = 0;
    int product = 0;
    // Ask for input/loop
    while (i < 3) {
        System.out.println("Please enter an integer greater than 3");
        i = input.nextInt();
    }
    for (int j = 2; j < i / 2; j++) {
        for (int k = 2; k < i / 2; k++) {
            if (j <= k && j * k <= i)
                System.out.println(j * k + " = " + j + "*" + k);
        }
    }
    // while (product < i) {
    // if (product == i) {
    // j++;
    // k = 2;
    // for (j = 2; product < i; k++) {
    // product = j * k;
    // System.out.println(product + " = " + j + " x " + k);
    // if (product == i) {
    // j++;
    // k = 2;
    // }
    // }
    // }
    // }
}
```

}

Comment: This is perfect and i owe you my life. This is so simple but nested loops are quite confusing to me. Thank you so much.